# Iterate nested json object in json-jquery

Tags: javascript, object

i am working on json nested object ,where i want to iterate it ,the code is as below .

```
var obj = { 
            user:  { name: "name1", country: "country1", city: "city1"  },
            user2: { name: "name2", country: "country2", city: "city2"  },
            user3 : { 
            user4: { 
            v1:  { c: "usa", ct: "Washingtion  ,D.C."  },
            v2:  { c: "Africa", ct: "South Africa"},
            v3 : { c: "Germany", ct: "Berlin"}
          }

          }
            }
```

Comment: What is your question? Btw there is no JSON in your code, just objects.

Comment: yes i want to iterate the object

Comment: it is not nested object in the example u have given

Comment: A nested object is iterated in the same way, just with nested loops.